# return ul in invoice parameters of paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

return ul in invoice parameters of paypal.
Can i set Return url parameter in invoice of paypal ?
after searching i get the link,
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/invoicing/CreateAndSendInvoice_API_Operation/
i see this link , but there is no explanation of return url .
Please help.If any one worked with it or know about it please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CreateAndSendInvoice doesn't get a ReturnURL because there is no redirection with PayPal happening there.  Your app is simply triggering the action of creating the invoice and sending an email to the user.  No browser redirects or anything would happen (unless you have done that sort of thing within your own) so there's no reason to supply PayPal with a ReturnURL since they won't need to return any user anywhere.

Maybe clarify what you're after within the CASI API and I can help more.